# Crystal report simple Header repeat issue

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any ways to repeat the Page header in every page without Pagegroup?I have built the report Which is having around 25 pages at least.
Design is like this

Report Header a : Paragraph  -1

Report Header  b : Paragraph  -2
                                 .
                                .
.
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
  Report Header  aa : Paragraph  -25

Page  Header  a : Page Header Text ( This text has be to displayed in repeated in every page)

Details – details

Page footer   : Page footer

Report Footer : report Footer

Comment: Page Headers repeat on every page unless you suppress them or your Report Header is not too lengthy. In case of a lengthy Report Header, as a workaround you can copy your Page Header contents in the Report Header too.

Comment: hi Harman ,  thanks for your suggestion .In which section I have to put the lengthy paragraph?